# C: scanf for char not working as expected

Tags: c, char, scanf

I was recently running a c program in my PC. It have a for loop in which some char d is scanned. The for loop runs for 3 times. During each running it prints the the count of running and then scans the value of char d. The program is as follows

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int f;
    char d;
    for(f=0;f<3;f++){
        printf("Choice %d\n", f);
        scanf("%c", &d);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now the trouble is that when I run the program, the for skips the scanf part when f is 1.
Now if i changed the code as follows

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int f;
    int d;
    for(f=0;f<3;f++){
        printf("Choice %d\n", f);
        scanf("%d", &d);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now the program works fine. and scanf is executed for every iteration of for loop.

What does seem to be the problem here? I mean when d is of type int it works fine, but when d is of type char it does not work correctly.

Comment: Why don't you read the `scanf()` manual? you are using it the wrong way anyway, even if you fix it.

Comment: Vivek, you are overwriting `d` 3 times.

Comment: @Jared Burrows can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: You loop over `scanf` and read into he same variable 3 times.

Comment: Well its just a part of larger program I am doing in which the for loop contain more code. I just posted the problematic bit here

Comment: @chux no no it is OK. As you can see I have received the answer. Once I added a space it worked correctly. scanf was working correctly but the overall execution made an unusual behavior in that part.

Comment: @chux Ohh I didn't give this title somebody must have changed it.

Comment: @chux its now more meaningful. Thanks.

Comment: @Vivek I'm taking down my comments as they only applied to someone else's weak editing and not your work.  This comment too - later.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You have to change

```
scanf("%c", &d);
```

to

```
scanf(" %c", &d);
       ^
       |
```

Otherwise, `scanf()` will consider the previously entered `ENTER` key press.

Note:

1. <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key press generates a `\n`, which is a vaild input for `%c` format specifier. Adding a space before `%c` tells `scanf()` to ignore all leading whitespace-like inputs (including that previously stored `\n`) and read the first non-whitespace character from `stdin`.
2. As for the case with `%d` format specifier, it consumes (and ignores) any leading whitespace-like inputs before scanning for numeric inputs, so the second case does not suffer any issues.

Comment: Oh thanks for the reply it worked like a charm. why does i need to do that ? i mean why add a space?

Comment: "`\n` is not a valid input for `%d` specifier" is misleading.   `\n` _is_ valid input for `"%d"` as that speciifer, unlike `"%c"`, first consumes leading white-space which includes `'\n'` before continuing and scanning for numeric input.

Comment: @chux Thank you sir for the input. Updated accordingly. Kindly review.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that when you enter a character for `scanf("%c", &d);`, you press the enter key. The character is consumed by the `scanf` and the newline character stays in the standard input stream(`stdin`). When `scanf`(with `%c`) is called the next time, it sees the `\n` character in the `stdin` and consumes it, and thus does not wait for further input.

To fix it, change

```
scanf("%c", &d);
```

to

```
scanf(" %c", &d);
//    ^Note the space before %c
```

The space before the `%c` instructs `scanf` to scan any number of whitespace characters including none and stops scanning when it encounters a non-whitespace character. Quoting the standard:

> **7.21.6.2 The fscanf function**
>
> [...]
>
> 5. A directive composed of white-space character(s) is executed by reading input up to the
>      first non-white-space character (which remains unread), or until no more characters can
>      be read. The directive never fails.

The reason that using `%d` worked is that the `%d` format specifier automatically skips whitespace characters and since `\n` is a whitespace character, `%d` does not scan it. Quoting the standard again:

> **7.21.6.2 The fscanf function**
>
> [...]
>
> 8. Input white-space characters (as specified by the `isspace` function) are skipped, unless
>      the specification includes a `[`, `c`, or `n` specifier. <sup>284</sup>