# C: scanf input single character and validation

Tags: c, scanf

I've encountered a problem when validating a single-char scanf input in C and I cannot find an existing solution that works...

The scenario is: a method is taking a single letter 'char' type input and then validating this input, if the criteria is not met, then pops an error message and re-enter, otherwise return this character value.

my code is:

```
char GetStuff(void)
{
    char c;
    scanf("%c", &c);
    while(c != 'A' || c != 'P')
    {
          printf("invalid input, enter again (A for AM or P for PM): ");
          scanf ("%c", &dtChar);
    }
    return c;
}
```

however, i got the infinite loop of error message no matter what input I type in. I read some other posts and guess it's the problem that %c specifier does no automatically get rid of the newline when I hit enter, and so far I have tried:

1. putting a white space before/after %c like:

   ```
   scanf(" %c", &c);
   ```
2. write a separate method or include in this `GetStuff` method to clean the newline like:

   ```
   void cleanBuffer(){
     int n;
     while((n = getchar()) != EOF && n != '\n' );
   }
   ```

Can anyone help me with this problem please? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C: scanf for char not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29122166/c-scanf-for-char-not-working-as-expected)

Comment: `c != 'A' || c != 'P'` is always true.

Comment: @n.m. you are right....but it still does work when I change || to &&

Comment: As well as fixing the loop condition, you should check the return value from `scanf()`; it might be telling you EOF.  You might well want to add a space before the `%c` in the conversion specifier, so as to skip white space (such as newlines) — using `if (scanf(" %c", &c) != 1) { …process error… }` might be better. You say that including fixed code in your bigger program still left you in an infinite loop. You should think about how you will debug it — adding print statements or using a debugger. See [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are using `scanf` for a single-character? Isn't that what `getchar()` (or `fgetc`) is for? You should also save and check the return of `scanf`, e.g. `int rtn = scanf ("%c", &c);` so you can check `if (rtn == EOF) { /* handle user canceled input */ }`

Comment: Can't help you with a non-current version of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

char GetStuff(void) {
    char c;
    scanf("%c", &c);
    getchar();
    while ((c != 'A') && (c != 'a') && (c != 'P') && (c != 'p')) {
        printf("invalid input, enter again (A for AM or P for PM): ");
        scanf ("%c", &c);
        getchar();
    }
    return c;
}

int main(void) {
    printf("Calling GetStuff()...\n");
    char x = GetStuff();
    printf("User entered %c\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

You are using **`while (c != 'A' || c != 'P')`** as your loop conditional, but this will always return true. What you meant to use is the **&&** "and" operator, instead of the **||** "or" operator.

Also, call `getchar()` after your scanf statements, to capture the newline. This should work the way you want it to.

Comment: for some reason the code works fine by itself, but when i use it in my actual code it stuck in the infinite loop again... the example I used is part of a bigger code, which just has several similar methods that prompts for input and then validate, and returns value to main if the input is good. but i didn't change any code structure for this method except the name of method/variable...could you think of any reasons why this would happen?

Comment: `getchar()` works in the way I used it, but I'm certain it wouldn't work or would interrupt the flow of a larger project. Have a look at @VolAnd 's answer, they have written a `CleanBuffer()` function that might work for you

Comment: I end up thinking it could be the enter key from a previous input (from another method in the complete code), so I added getchar() in other methods whenever i have a scanf input and it seemed working :)

Comment: I'm glad :) If my answer worked for you, please mark it as "accepted" by clicking the check mark to the left of it.

Answer (score 3):

Please consider the following snippet:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char GetStuff(void)
{
    char c;
    do {
          printf("Please enter A for AM or P for PM: ");
          scanf ("%c", &c);
          // clean input buffer (till the end of line)
          while(getchar()!='\n');
    } while(toupper(c) != 'A' && toupper(c) != 'P');
    return c;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("Your input is'%c'\n", GetStuff());
    return 0;
}
```

Note the points:

- condition `while(c != 'A' || c != 'P')` will be always true (just because one character cannot be 'A' and 'P' at the same time), so use `while(c != 'A' && c != 'P')` instead
- No need for two `scanf` if you use `do..while` loop
- After entering a char with `scanf` it is recommended to clean all characters from buffer, e.g. with `while(getchar()!='\n');` (this will clean all input including incorrect and redundant characters)
- use `toupper` to avoid making 4 comparison (actually single `c=toupper(c)` inside loop can minimize your while as `while(c != 'A' && c != 'P')` )

**UPDATE:**

To add message "Invalid input" and adding some other useful improvement subjected befor... new code is as:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void CleanBuffer(){
    int n;
    while((n = getchar()) != EOF && n != '\n' );
}

char GetStuff(void)
{
    char c;
    do {
          printf("Please enter A for AM or P for PM: ");
          scanf (" %c", &c);
          c = toupper(c); // here letter become uppercase
          CleanBuffer();
    } while( (c != 'A' && c != 'P')?printf("Invalid input! "):0 );
    return c;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("You have entered: %c\n", GetStuff());
    return 0;
}
```

**Note:** function will return 'A' or 'P' in uppercase, so if this is not needed change the code as in example before update (use two `toupper` and do not change `c` after `scanf`). Also you can use `tolower` as an option (of course with comparing to `'a'` and `'p'`).

Comment: for that while statement in the `CleanBuffer` method, I see there is no statement following the while statement, does it mean the code will be continued (so the code execution for `GetStuff ` will be continued) if the condition `(n = getchar()) != EOF && n != '\n' ` is true?, otherwise `n` will take up the redundant characters?

Comment: and what would be the difference if I simply use `getchar()` after `scanf` in `GetStuff ` instead of using a separate `CheanBuffer ` method with `while((n = getchar()) != '\n')` statement?

Comment: difference between single `getchar()` and loop in `CheanBuffer` will be clear when you enter several letters instead of one, e.g.: enter `qwert`while program asks for `A` or `P`

Answer (score 1):

Inside loop you are taking input in  `dtChar` but your loop condition checks variable `c` which is not updated in the loop, that is causing infinite loop

Also you would change your condition

```
while(c != 'A' || c != 'P')
```

to

```
while(c != 'A' && c != 'P')
```

If you want user to enter either 'A' or 'P'

Comment: my bad...i didn't edit my code for posting completely, i will correct it now

Comment: you are right with the condition in while loop, but the code still does work when i change || to &&

Comment: Have you accounted for condition variable that I pointed out in answer, you can assign c to dtChar prior to loop and change condition variable to dtChar instead of c

Comment: yes i did. I actually have only one local variable in this methods which is c, and the condition variable used for starting the while loop is also c. c is also the value to be returned at the end of this method.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution. As others mentioned the condition was to be done with &&. Anyway the big problem is how to remove what's left on the console input line. Since the console works by lines, we remove everything up to the next `'\n'`. If the user already left something on the input line before calling `GetStuff()`, it would be useful to add a call to `SkipRestOfTheLine()` before the while loop.

In general I suggest to start with a `while(1)` loop, before making it nicer (such as in the `cleanBuffer()` you posted).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void SkipRestOfTheLine(void)
{
    while (1) {
        int c = fgetc(stdin);
        if (c == EOF || c == '\n')
            break;
    }
}

char GetStuff(void)
{
    while (1) {
        int c = fgetc(stdin);
        if (c == EOF)
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE); // Deal with this case in an appropriate way
        if (c == 'A' || c == 'P')
            return c;
        printf("invalid input, enter again (A for AM or P for PM): ");
        SkipRestOfTheLine();
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char c = GetStuff();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: yes, I think this part of the code as what i posted didn't work when I put it back to my complete code is because there is already something in the buffer due to the enter key from previous `scanf ` input in my code (my complete code prompts for multiple inputs). i got away with the problem by adding `getchar()` to clean buffer up after every input

Comment: for this assignment I am working on, I wasn't allowed to use `break`, but your suggestion for cleaning up what is left from the previous input is very helpful.

Answer (score -1):

try this,

```
   char GetStuff(void)
    {
        char c;
        scanf("%c", &c);
        while (((c != 'A') || (c != 'a')) && ((c != 'P') || (c != 'p'))==1)
        {
              printf("invalid input, enter again (A for AM or P for PM): ");
              scanf ("%c", &dtChar);
        }
        return c;
    }
```

I hope this works, some time because of not given proper bracket it is stuck in the loop.

Comment: "I hope this works" is not an answer. "some time" is not appropriate for a `while` condition in C.

Answer (score -2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
char c;
do{
printf("invalid input, enter again (A for AM or P for PM): ");
scanf ("%s", &c);
}while ((c != 'A') && (c != 'P'));
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please add explanations to your code snippet.

Comment: New answers to old, well-answered questions should contain ample explanation on how they complement the other answers.